# Refresh page give difference style result after adding form element

Tags: php, html, css

I found a strange behaviour in my css style. I created a login page that can be accessed from a link wihtin home page. If I access login page from a link within home page or login page itself, everything looks fine. But, whenever I refresh login page, the header looks weird. And all of this happen only if `<form>` element is exists, without `<form>` element, there's no problem.

So, what causes this to happen? And how do I fix this?

**Note:** *Everything after this is only attachment for my question details.*

The login file page written like this:

```
<?php require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/config/core.php'); ?>

<html>
<?php include_once($root.'/includes/head.php');?>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<?php include_once($root.'/includes/header.php');?>
<?php include_once($root.'/includes/navigation.php');?>
    <section>
        <article>
            <h2>Login</h2>
            <form action="<?php echo $current_file;?>" method="post">
            <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="15">
                <tr>
                    <td width="100">Username</td>
                    <td>:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="username" maxlength="50" size="35"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Password</td>
                    <td>:</td>
                    <td><input type="password" name="password" maxlength="50" size="35"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3" align="center"><input type="submit" value="  Login  "><input type="submit" value="  Reset  "></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            </form>
        </article>
    </section>

<?php include_once($root.'/includes/news.php');?>
<?php include_once($root.'/includes/footer.php');?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The `header.php` file that I included written like this:

```
<header>
    <div id="logo">
        <img src="/images/arh.png" />
        <h1>The Header</h1>
    </div>
</header>
```

And, the css file for header element is written like this:

```
header {
    background-color: #000; height: 120px;
}

#logo {
    float: left;
}

#logo img {
    height: 100px; padding: 10px;
}

#logo h1 {
    color: #ccc; float: right; font-size: 36px; padding: 30px;
}
```

The result if i access `login.php` page from link:

[image: From link]

And, if i refresh the page:

[image: With refresh]

Comment: You should consider putting the header file in the body part of the html.

Comment: Is this by any chance happening in Chrome?

Comment: Maybe this is the case: `<form action="<?php echo $current_file;?>" method="post">` ? If there's any error, it might ruin your HTML. Try checking if `$current_file` exists first: `<form action="<?= isset($current_file) ? $current_file : '';?>" method="post">`

Comment: @AndreiP the header is in body part, except it's included with php, but it's echoed in body part. @RST it's in chrome. @matewka it still happens even though i used `<form action="login.php">`

Answer (score 0):

i had pretty much that same problem. Matewka is right.

there was a small error in my html on my header.  i had my div in the middle of my table.

What i had

```
<div>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
        </td>
    </tr>
</div>
</table>
```

what i changed it to

```
<div>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

I just moved my div to the end of my table. I don't know how i did this, but being up for a few days or staring at the same thing over and over you start missing things.  I would double check the html, it might be that simple.  (are you using height % ?) do you have borders?